# A, B, and C Roll Dice

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

Hello I have the following question:

Three players A, B, & C take turns rolling a pair of dice. The winner is the first player who obtains the sum of 7 (P[7] = 1/6) on a given roll of the dice. If A rolls 1st, then B, then C, then back to A (etc. etc. etc.). What is the P[A wins], P[B wins], P[C wins]?

I know the P[A]= 36/91 with it being a geometric series of (1/6)/[1-(125/216)]
What confuses me is why does the beginning of the series start as: 1/6 + (5/6)^3(1/6)
Why is it cubed and not squared since there are only 2 other possible winners other than A?

Comment: Ugh that's right.  Probability rust.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A wins if they succeed immediately, or if there are first three(!) failures by A, B, C and then a success by A, etc.

---

Alternative approach: If A happens to fail on first roll (with probability $\frac 56$) , we essentially start a game with players$(B,C,A)$ instead of $(A,B,C)$.
Therefore $P[B]=\frac 56P[A]$, $P[C]=\frac 56 P[B]$, and $P[A]=\frac 16+\frac56P[C]$. You can solve these three equations in three unknowns

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Round 1 : A wins with probability $1/6$

Round 2 : B wins with probability $1/6 \times (5/6)$

Round 3 : C wins with probability $1/6 \times (5/6)^2$

Round 4 : A wins with probability $1/6 \times (5/6)^3$

etc.

There is a cube because A has to wait three times for his turn to come again.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense